# What i have to do in my app to receive payments? (java - spring)

Tags: spring, web-applications, payment

I am developing a portal where users to access, must buy a plan. This portal is being developed with angular + spring.

To purchase the plan will have to be through PayPal or by entering the credit card information.
I know that PayPal has an API for this case and I have no doubt.

How can I do to implement this logic payments with credit cards? The server part is java soon recommend the use of a service, it must be compatible with Java.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use Paypal Java SDK (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK). The repository contains working example of performing REST calls to Paypal API, so it should be easy to create a specific Spring service within your app to make use of these calls.

Comment: But this is only to receive payments through PayPal, right? I can receive a payment from credit card with PayPal sdk?

Comment: Actually you can receive payments from CC with this SDK, please take a look at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/payments/servlet/PaymentWithCreditCardServlet.java sample servlet